# preg_replace and comment_form_defaults

Tags: regex, allowedtags

this was kinda of a joke at the beginning but now I'm wondering if it's possible to use regex with the hook comment_form_defaults. Here is what I'm looking for :

```
function remove_default_allowed_tags( $defaults) {
    $defaults = preg_replace('/<p class="form-allowed-tags">(.*?)<\/p>/','', $defaults);
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'remove_default_allowed_tags', 2);
```

I know it can be easily done with something like this :
`$defaults['comment_notes_after'] = ''; return $defaults;`

But I just want to know if I can use my regex in this context and if not, why. 
Thanks for your answer(s).

Comment: You could, but why would you run a regex pattern over the whole array when you only need to update a single key in that array? Lots of needless processing.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a better way but I want to use my regex

Comment: You want to use your regex to do what? And why do you want to use regex if there is some other solution?

Comment: Why do you feel you need the regex? I don't follow.

Comment: Guys I do not need it. Just wanted to know if it's possible. Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex anywhere you have a string to manipulate. That is basic PHP. There is nothing special about WordPress that changes that.

But why use regex when there are other options? As much fun as it is, regex is tricky and easy to get wrong, and there is significant overhead to using it.

What you are doing generates an "array to string conversion" `Notice`, by the way. [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will accept an array of strings as the third parameter but `$defaults['fields']` is an array so you get an `Notice` so it wouldn't work as expected if you tried to alter that field.

Comment: Ok then. I just wanted to know if it's possible, I'm not saying I want to use it every time I have to alter allowed tags. Thanks

Comment: I just made it work by putting $defaults['comment_notes_after'] in the preg_match() and I didn't get any notice. So it works. Thanks ! Again, I do not encourage people using that.